# How to convert timestamp from sas to ordinary timestamp

Tags: sql, sas

I have SAS timestamp like 28JUL14:11:07:17 and I want to convert it to timestamp like 2014-07-28 11:07:17.0 using sql. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert".  There is no need to change the value to display it using a different format.

Answer (score 4):

Format your variable using one of the many ISO formats available.

Example:

```
format mytimestamp E8601DT.;
```

From help

> E8601DTw.d Format
>
> Writes datetime values in the ISO 8601 extended notation yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff.